# Order of column values to new column value

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table as:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 23 | 15 | 17 | 9 | 21 |
| 9 | 13 | 15 | 19 | 4 | 2 |
| 26 | 11 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 21 |

I want to add a new column, where the value is concatenation of the 6 column names, in descending order of the values, like this:

| code |
| --- |
| BFDCAE |
| DCBAEF |
| AFEBCD |

I tried using GREATEST() and LEAST() but that leads to at least 6!=720 lines of code, which I want to avoid. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that the data you want to sort is stored across columns and not across rows. SQL is designed to work across rows. Change your data structure and you can use group_concat with order by to generate the result you want.

Comment: Does it have to be done directly in an SQL statement? If you could use an additional programming language, such as PHP, this would become quite a bit easier to do ... Read the values from each row into an associative array, sort that as desired, and then join the keys in their new order together again, and then update the record with that.

Comment: @Shadow I understand your point, but functions like GREATEST() and LEAST() exist in SQL to work within rows, so I suspect there is a way.

Comment: Of course you can do this... but this is non-relational. Does the primary key exists your table?

Comment: There is a way, but these functions only tell you the greatest / smallest value from a list. They do not preserve the associated value (column name), nor can they rank the entire list of values. If you do not want to do things in the sql way, then I would go with CBroe's suggestion and do this calculation outside of mysql.

Comment: It would be possible to implement a REALLY UGLY solution without normalizing the data IF the table had a primary key. Without a primary key, this is not possible with non-procedural code.

Comment: @symcbean *Without a primary key, this is impossible.* If PK is absent then unique row identifier can be added/generated. Alternatively we may group the rows and get duplicates amount and finally generate needed output rows for dupicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( -- add a column with unique value
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 (rn, val, col) AS ( -- normalize data
  SELECT rn, A, 'A' FROM cte1 UNION ALL
  SELECT rn, B, 'B' FROM cte1 UNION ALL
  SELECT rn, C, 'C' FROM cte1 UNION ALL
  SELECT rn, D, 'D' FROM cte1 UNION ALL
  SELECT rn, E, 'E' FROM cte1 UNION ALL
  SELECT rn, F, 'F' FROM cte1
  )
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col ORDER BY val DESC, col ASC SEPARATOR '') code
FROM cte2
GROUP BY rn;
```

| code |
| --- |
| BFDCAE |
| DCBAEF |
| AFEBCD |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3lKsVRW6)

If the table is more wide than provided one, and primary key exists in it, then it must be used instead of `rn`, and `cte1` must be removed.

Additional `col ASC` in ORDER BY makes the output deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using `UNION ALL` and `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, GROUP_CONCAT(col_id ORDER BY col_value DESC) AS CODE
FROM (
  SELECT *, A as col_value, 'A' col_id
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT *, B, 'B' 
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT *, C, 'C'
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT *, D, 'D'
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT *, E, 'E'
  FROM mytable
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT *, F, 'F'
  FROM mytable
) AS s
GROUP BY A  ,B, C,  D,  E,  F;
```

Results :

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   CODE
9   13  15  19  4   2   D,C,B,A,E,F
12  23  15  17  9   21  B,F,D,C,A,E
26  11  6   3   15  21  A,F,E,B,C,D
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/d0Q3xbTU)

Comment: It would be better then if the information was stored in a normalised manner in the first place, not statically unpivoted.

Comment: None guarantees that the rows are unique. And in this case the output will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 8.0.14 mysql finally added support for lateral joins officialy called [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html)

At first it is like doing standard Union All, but there is a big difference as this code **scans the table only once** significantly **improving performance**.

```sql
/*  S a m p l e    D a t a :  */
WITH
    tbl (A, B, C, D, E, F) AS
        ( Select 12, 23, 15, 17, 9, 21 From Dual Union All 
          Select 9, 13, 15, 19, 4, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 26, 11, 6, 3, 15, 21 From Dual 
        ),
```

```sql
/*  C T E   -  C r o s s   J o i n   L a t e r a l :  */
   tbl_rows AS
        ( Select t.ID, x.*
          From  ( Select ROW_NUMBER() Over() as ID, A, B, C, D, E, F From tbl ) t
          Cross Join  Lateral ( Select A, 'A' Union All 
                                Select B, 'B' Union All
                                Select C, 'C' Union All
                                Select D, 'D' Union All
                                Select E, 'E' Union All
                                Select F, 'F' 
                              ) as x (col1, col2)
        )
```

```sql
/*    M a i n   S Q L :   */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col2 ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC SEPARATOR '') as code
FROM tbl_rows
GROUP BY ID;
```

```sql
/*   R e s u l t :
code
--------
BFDCAE
DCBAEF
AFEBCD  */
```